# How to trace low-level output for Redis server

Tags: redis, jedis

I want to trace all low-level output that the Jedis client sends via JedisCommands to the Redis server. Should I enable logging to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to trace the Redis commands or response?

If you want to trace commands, just use the [monitor](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command. 
You can simply execute `redis-cli monitor`.

If you want to trace the response, it seems there are no logging mechanism in Jedis. 
You need to either modify your application code or edit Jedis source to add logging.

---

Update:

I think RedisToGo forbids `monitor` command because performance concern. Because Jedis didn't provide built-in logging mechanism, the most simple way is modify and built Jedis on your own.

In Jedis, all Redis command should go through the 2 `sendCommand` methods in [redis.clients.jedis.Connection](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/b7ee1fe29a54036064e5546a4d26b8ff5110d8d8/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Connection.java#L79-91) class. Just try to add 2 lines of code there for logging. Any logging library should be applicable, such as `log4j`, `java.util.logging` or even `System.out`.

Comment: The monitor command fails with the following error on RedisToGo ERR operation not permitted. I don't mind using this command if it works, else I would like to know if there is an option which I can enable on my client based on jedis.

Answer (score 0):

I use Jedis 4.4.3. In the code I didn't find any 'log' for commands.
But it is possible to turn on the logging at Redis server level.

RedisInsight (tool from https://redis.com) recommends this:
"Use Profiler tool to see all the requests processed by the server."

[RedisInsight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLIvv.png)